# bash extracting id3 information

Tags: bash, shell, substring, id3

I am working on a script that displays id3 tag information on mp3 files for school.
I have been able to get the last line but have had trouble in getting the metadata.

The metadata starts with the string TAG. My script gets the position of that string and then tries to extract the line starting at that position.

What is being outputted was the last line but before the meta data starts.

I have changed the numbers and yet the output is not changing with one exception. File1 when I intentionally extract from pos 76 which is less than the match I get a few more of the characters like I would expect.

the script

```
for f in *.mp3
do
  echo;
  echo;
  echo  the last line of the file is;
  lastLine=`tail -1 $f`
  echo $lastLine;
  echo;
  pos=`expr index "$lastLine" TAG`;
  echo  match is found at pos $pos;
  echo getting the string starting at pos 122;
  echo ${lastLine:122}
  echo;
  echo getting the string starting at pos 150;
  echo ${lastLine:150}
  echo;
  echo getting the string starting at pos 76;
  echo ${lastLine:76}
  echo;
done
```

the output from 2 different mp3 files

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it's not a requirement then I suggest to use `mp3info` (http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info/)

Comment: unfortunately I have to do it from scratch for the class.

Comment: "Last line" is pretty meaningless in a binary file. Do you mean you have to extract "The last C-string containing only printable text?" Or "The id3v2 comment tag"?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing binary data can be a real annyance with shell scripts, especially when the actual coding is undefined, as with ID3 tags. As php-coder proposed, you might want to use a tool that does the handling for you.

Comment: It is not an option since it is for school however is there a way to simply remove the binary characters from the string since all I need to parse is after the binary?

Comment: @yamikoWebs: Are you forbidden from using `od`, `dd` and other tools?

Comment: @Sorpigal You will need to find a tool that does handle binary encoding flexibly (code pages). The used encoding is needed to be guessed. Moreover, looking for "TAG" somewhere (it might be in fact at the end of file) is not exactly error tolerant. There are not many tools suitable for these tasks, e.g. dd, od are not.

Comment: @artsenay: I agree. In general doing this in `bash` is crazy, I'm simply trying to reduce the crazy to a manageable level.

Comment: I can use commands as long as I'm not using one that does what I'm doing. for example I can not use a command that will get the id3 tags for me but using commands like dd and od are fine. I'm busy atm Ill look at the answers in a few hours and thanks for the input thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You can `echo` to `strings` to get rid of those unprintable characters

```
$ echo -e '\x87hello\x99' | strings
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

for f; do
  echo -e "\n\n\nthe last line of the file is"
  lastLine=$(strings $f | tail -1)
  echo $lastLine
  echo
  pos=$(expr index "$lastLine" TAG)
  cat<<EOF
  match is found at pos $pos
  getting the string starting at pos 122
  ${lastLine:122}

  getting the string starting at pos 150
  ${lastLine:150}

  getting the string starting at pos 76
  ${lastLine:76}
EOF
done
```

then

`./script *mp3`

That uses `strings` see `man 1 strings`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

boff=3
bytes=3
tag=$(tail -c "$boff" "$1" | head -c "$bytes")

while [ "$tag" != "TAG" ] ; do
    let boff+=1
    tag=$(tail -c "$boff" "$1" | head -c "$bytes")
done

tail -c "$boff" "$1"
```

To extract from TAG to end of file? You may then filter however you need.